# Azure Data Factory failed on Build server The remote name could not be resolved: 'datafactories.schema.management.azure.com'

Tags: azure, tfsbuild, azure-data-factory

I have Data Factory project in my solution. It compiled successfully on my machine. But when I triggered it from my tfs build server DataFactory throws an error at ParameterConfig.json

> MsBuild\1.0\DataFactory.targets (35): Failed to download JSON schema
>   http://datafactories.schema.management.azure.com/internalschemas/2015-01-01-preview/Microsoft.DataFactory.Table.json
>   with exception message The remote name could not be resolved:
>   'datafactories.schema.management.azure.com'

I have added $schema in all the datasets, pipeline, and ParameterConfig files. This issue is **intermittent**. Someday it fails someday it works.

Comment: Since the issue is intermittent, when it happened, are you able to build it on your own machine?

Comment: @Cece Dong - MSFT  Yes.  I can build successfully on my local machine. No issues at all.

Comment: Why do you need to build the files? I add them to my solution, but do not build them, I take them as artifacts from my build.

Comment: @SimonZeinstra I am trying to build Data Factory Project.

Comment: Yes, but why? It's is not necessary to build the project. The only use I see is to check for integrity of the files?

Comment: @SimonZeinstra I need to use the parameterized datasets, linked service, and pipelines for the deployment. The parameterized files generate after the compilation.

Comment: @Rohi_Dev_1.0 As the issue is intermittent, it's hard for us to troubleshoot it. You may try to login your build agent machine, and build the project manually with MSBuild command line to see whether you can reproduce this issue.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I checked the same getting same issue and still, someday I got the error some day it works. Is it something related to Target file permissions or something changing behind the extensions. The dll Microsoft.WindowsAzure.DataFactoryStudio.DataFactoryProject.dll causing the issue

Comment: @Rohi_Dev_1.0 You may open an issue on the publisher's GitHub repository for extension related questions: https://github.com/liprec/vsts-publish-adf/issues?utm_source=vsmp&utm_medium=ms%20web&utm_campaign=mpdetails

Answer (score 1):

After lot more brainstorming I come to know that its totally intermittent issue. 
I got related issues in Keyvault stuff also. Same error saying "Remote name could not be resolved". 
What I observed is the URL mentioned above "http://datafactories.schema.management.azure.com" is not accessible from my build server account. So I used the trick and it works for me.
I have added "http://datafactories.schema.management.azure.com" site as a trusted site on my build server Internet settings.
It works! I didn't get any issues till now. My build is succeeded all the time.